# How to prove that for any $n\in N$, there exists a subset of real line that has nonempty $(n-1)^{th}$ derived set but an empty $n^{th}$ derived set?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

How can we prove that for any positive integer n, i.e., $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a subset of real numbers, i.e., $E\subset \mathbb{R}$, that has nonempty $(n-1)^{th}$ derived set but an empty $n^{th}$ derived set?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Draw ordinal  $\omega^{n-1}$ on real line. Here is picture of [$\omega^2$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aOmega_squared.png). You can see that it's derived set is $\omega$ and derived set of $\omega$ is just a point.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X\subset \mathbb{R}$ be any set of reals containing only isolated points.  Then we can define a function $d:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that the intervals $(x, x + d(x))$ are mutually disjoint for all $x\in X$.  The set
$$
X'= \bigcup_{x\in X}\left\{x+d(x), x+\frac{1}{2}d(x), x+\frac{1}{3}d(x),\ldots\right\}
$$
has derived set $X$ and contains only isolated points.  Starting with $X_1=\{0\}$, then, you can generate a set with the desired property by induction using $X_{n+1}=X_{n}'$.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the following lemma $n$ times, starting with the empty set:

**Lemma.** Given any closed set $X\subseteq\mathbb R$ we can construct a closed set $Y\subseteq\mathbb R$ such that $X$ is the derived set of $Y$.

In proving the lemma, it may be helpful to consider $\mathbb R\setminus X$ as a union of disjoint open intervals.